# process.argv is undefined in node.js

Tags: node.js

I can't seem to be running the most trivial of scripts in node:

Platform: windows 10

node -v: v10.7.0

file: "sample.js"

```
process.argv.forEach((val, index) => {
    console.log(`${index}: ${val}`);
  });
```

command line:

```
D:\temp>node sample.js 1 2 3
D:\temp\sample.js:4
process.argv.forEach((val, index) => {
             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\temp\sample.js:4:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:266:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:596:3)
```

Comment: Is that the whole code? what's `console.log(process)`?

Comment: The code is correct, Reinstall node.js.

Comment: Console.log(process) shows this: "[Function: process]"

Comment: Show us the entire `sample.js` file.  Specifically, what is on lines 1-3 before line 4 with your `process.argv.forEach()`?  I guarantee one of those 3 lines before is redefining `process` to be a `Function` instead of the `Object` it's supposed to be.

Comment: @Parsa thanks a lot. that fixed my problem

Comment: @dossy That is the entire file. There's nothing to it. If there are args print them. That why the whole thing is so puzzling.

Comment: @Parsa consider adding your solution as an answer

Comment: @dossy Thanks, that fixed it for me. I'd defined a `process()` function. Doh.

Comment: @DarrenCook Heh, that's what I suspected - thanks for confirming.  And, ouch!  :)

Answer (score 16):

**Solution**

I figured out, that I defined the function process below, that's why process object was overridden by my own.

So, to resolve:

1. Check that you are  not overriding "process" object with a function
2. Put it initialization higher line by line and find what code is
       overriding it

**Old suggestion:**

In my case, it was "redefined" even if I put it on the first line. "Process" was a function.

To retrieve Object I used explicit call:

`const process = require('process');`

Answer (score 3):

Reiterating my comment as an answer, as [DarrenCook confirmed I was correct in his particular case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52807556/process-argv-is-undefined-in-node-js/53963545#comment94736890_52807556):

Show us the entire `sample.js` file. Specifically, what is on lines 1-3 before line 4 with your `process.argv.forEach()`? I guarantee one of those 3 lines before is redefining `process` to be a `Function` instead of the `Object` it's supposed to be.

Comment: This just saved me a big headache!

Answer (score -6):

The code is correct, Reinstall node.js.

Comment: Why would reinstalling fix it? Is that a common problem on Windows, or node 10.7.0??